# Why space makes a difference in the style using white space, and how to solve this?

Tags: html, css

In this sample

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
      .q_show_spaces {
          white-space: pre-wrap;
    }

    .q_inline {
        display: inline;
    }

    .q_no_wrap {
        white-space: pre;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:400px;border:solid 1px">
    <div class="q_show_spaces"><div class="q_inline">To    testaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </div><div class="q_inline q_no_wrap"><div class="q_inline">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaabbb, </div></div><div class="q_inline">by like terms</div></div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div style="width:400px;border:solid 1px">
    <div class="q_show_spaces"><div class="q_inline">To    testaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </div><div class="q_inline q_no_wrap"><div class="q_inline">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaabbb,</div></div><div class="q_inline"> by like terms</div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the first example, content is going outside the div, but in second example content is as expected, only change is that space is moved out of div.

How to fix this? I dont want to move space outside, also do not want to remove any div or styles on div. suggest any new style which can override these and work correctly.

Sorry for improper formatting of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for `word-break: break-all` css property.

Apply like this in your css:

```
 .q_show_spaces {
     white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-all; /* or break-work, if you planning to break a word */
 }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/U4N2a/)

[MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Comment: Looks like perfectly this is what i am looking for.

Comment: @madhu_p please mark it as answer if it answers your question.

Comment: using break-all wrapping the characters
check http://jsfiddle.net/P4pkL/
also q_no_wrap not working if we use break-word

Comment: @madhu_p I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4pkL/2/). Is this what you want?

Comment: I need show_space style to preserve spaces, please check http://jsfiddle.net/P4pkL/3/

Comment: every thing looks perfect in your sample http://jsfiddle.net/P4pkL/1/ except preserve space.